# How to open odt files on Eclipse (In-Place Editor)?

Tags: eclipse, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I try to open odt files with LibreOffice 6.0 on Eclipse Photon/Oxygen (Open with -> In-Place Editor), but it does not work. LibreOffice opens but not very well.

I can open via "Open with -> System/Default Editor". But in both cases the files are openned external to Eclipse.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, i.e. its main purpose is to edit *source code*. LibreOffice text files (.odt) are not source code. What you ask is not possible.

Comment: Eclipse is not only to edit source code. There are table editor (e.g. NatTable), model editor (e.g. Papyrus), etc. Furthermore, it is possible to open docx in Eclipse.